# How to change popup in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to using Eclipse (I just downloaded it).
I began creating a new project, wrote some code, added some packages and classes and closed the project.

Now, I opened it again and I'd like to add a class to a package. So I right-click on that package and the standard popup window appears. But when I now hover over "New ->", there are only three options: "Project", "Example" and "Other". The first time I worked on the project, there were many more options, f.ex. I was able to click on "Class" direct. Right now, I have to select "Other", type "Class" into another window and click "Ok".

Is there any switch or so in the settings that I accidentally enabled that changes the default right-click popup?

I added an image.

Thank you for help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not in the Java perspective: ***Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Java***

Comment: So easy... Thanks a lot, you solved a lot of my time! ;-) I also didn't found anything about that on the internet.